# VLC, realtime priority and rtkit

Tags: linux, video, vlc-media-player, real-time

How can I increase the priority of VLC to some realtime level? The realtime setting inside of VLC does not seem to have any effect. I figure it nowerdays (on a modern Linux system, not a from scratch system) involves rtkit.

I have already tried using `vlc-wrapper` and setting this to `+s`.

Plus I figure that most of the time my system is "sluggish", this involes heavy memory usage. Is there any way to *priorize memory for VLC*?

Any pointers?

Comment: Can you expand on heavy memory usage? I have a hard time believing that memory access would is the weakest link slowing you system down. *Unless* you run out of memory and are using swap.

Comment: I have had some issue with VLC lagging out on an older computer. Increasing buffersize solved it for me

Comment: It's only happening when e.g. a web browser eats a lot of memory. So yes, unless I'm multitasking it is fine. No issues when just watching TV. And yes, the computer may need to swap, I only have 1 GB, and today web browsers are darn memory hungry. If I weren't multitasking I would not need to increase the priority. But I want VLC to get priority over all other stuff (and no, I don't want to put "nice" in front of every other command).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing nice level with the nice command?

```
nice -0 vlc
```

if it works you can put it in a bash-script and create an alias to vlc, so it will always start with nice 0

Comment: You can't go above 0 with this, unless you are root. And running all this as root is not recommended. Which is exactly what rtkit is meant to solve.